# delete sql rows that have same value in next row

Tags: sql, select, apache-spark-sql

I have got table with column values as below: I need to remove / select the rows where subsequent values for column event is repeating and make a pair of rows with column event with values 1,2. Can anybody help in writing a ANSI SQL code to be used in Spark SQL.

[image]

With Thanks
Gopinathan K. M

Answer (score 0):

If your table have an `auto_increment` id field, you can do as you request using this:

```
DELETE FROM table t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from table t2 
              WHERE t1.event= t2.event
              AND t2.id + 1 = t1.id)
```

Comment: It doesn't have any auto-increment field.

Comment: You MUST have a table with a column with unique values in order to know which one to refer.

Comment: For any employee, the columns empno and badge will remain same

Comment: create a column called employee_id, set it to auto_increment. Then you will be able to do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same situation as you. I have solved it. See the code below:

```
SELECT * [Table_Name] BILLION
INNER JOIN [Table_Name] T1 ON T.Emp= T1.Emp AND T.Badge= T1.Badge -- previous data[1]
WHERE T1.Time = (SELECT MAX(Time) FROM [Table_Name] T2 WHERE T2.staff_id = T.staff_id AND T2.Time < T.Time) AND T.Event= T1.Event [2]
```

[1]: The condition to find the previous record depends on your problem. In the above example, 2 fields (Emp and Badge) are search pairs.

[2]: Additional condition, in case (Emp and Badge) is a search pair, the remaining condition here is Event